# how can i use updated value of Variable at each iteration in Pyomo?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to solve an Optimization problem that has a variable x (initialize =0) which has an updated value after solving the problem using SolverFactory. In the second iteration, I want the optimization problem to use value of x obtained from the first iteration instead of initialized value. How do I do that?

Comment: Initialize it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [persistent solvers](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/persistent_solvers.html) if you use CPLEX or Gurobi. If not, look into the [warmstart parameter](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_models.html#warm-starts) for the `solve` command. Persistent solver will load the problem only once into the solver, letting you run it multiple times. The `warmstart=True` parameter will load the model into the solver everytime, but initialized variables will make a starting solution (if feasible).